# Find row-wise minimum positive non-zero number in data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a numeric data frame

```
A <- c(1.1, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.3)
B <- c(0.2, 1.0, 2.4, 1.1, 1.3, 0.0)
C <- c(5.2, 1.3, 3.7, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0)

data <- data.frame(A, B, C) %>% as_tibble()
```

how can I create another column containing the row-wise minimum positive non-zero number (using dplyr if possible) to obtain the following data frame?

```
## A tibble: 6 x 4
#      A     B     C posmin
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1   1.1   0.2   5.2    0.2
#2   3     1     1.3    1  
#3   2     0     3.7    2  
#4   4     1.1   1.7    1.1
#5   0     1.3   1.3    1.3  
#6   1.3   0     1      1
```

---

What's concise and almost does the job is

```
data %>% mutate(posmin = pmin(A, B, C))
```

which has two issues, however:

- My real data frame has more columns (A to Z) and I can't call `pmin(A:Z)`
- `pmin` computes the row-wise minimum

Is there something like `pminpos` and if there isn't how can I create it so that it can be called just like `pmin` in the code above? And how do I specify many contiguous columns without passing a comma-separated list of their names?

Thank you very much.

*edit*: I clearly missed to stress the point, that I'm looking for **non-zero positive numbers**, i.e. numbers strictly greater than > 0. Hence the sought-after values for rows #5 and #6 are not zero.

Comment: min value for row 5 and 6 should be 0, shouldn't they?

Comment: @JilberUrbina I'm looking for numbers strictly greater than zero. Sorry for the ambiguity - I adjusted my question's wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `invoke` and use `na_if` as commented by [@markus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469836/find-row-wise-minimum-positive-number-in-data-frame-using-dplyr/52470750#comment91883542_52470750)

```
   data %>% 
       mutate(posmin = invoke(pmin, na_if(., 0), na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
      A     B     C posmin
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   1.1   0.2   5.2    0.2
2   3     1     1.3    1  
3   2     2.4   3.7    2  
4   4     1.1   1.7    1.1
5   0     1.3   1.3    1.3
6   1.3   0     1      1
```

Comment: Or do `data %>% mutate(posmin = invoke(pmin, na_if(., 0), na.rm = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to convert the column names to symbols and then evaluate (`!!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(replace(., .==0, NA))) %>% 
   transmute(posmin = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   bind_cols(data, .)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
#      A     B     C posmin
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1   1.1   0.2   5.2    0.2
#2   3     1     1.3    1  
#3   2     2.4   3.7    2  
#4   4     1.1   1.7    1.1
#5   0     1.3   1.3    1.3  
#6   1.3   0     1      1
```

Or use `map/reduce`

```
map(data, na_if, 0) %>% 
    reduce(pmin, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    bind_cols(data, posmin = .)
```

---

Or without using any external packages, we can call `pmin` within `do.call` in a single line

```
data$posmin <- do.call(pmin, c(NA^ (data == 0) * data, na.rm = TRUE))
data$posmin
#[1] 0.2 1.0 2.0 1.1 1.3 1.0
```

Or based on @Moody_Mudskipper's comments, instead of assigning value that are 0 to `NA`, change it to a larger value (`Inf`) and then use `pmin`

```
data$posmin <- do.call(pmin, '[<-'(data, data <=0, value=Inf))
```

Comment: I think OP looks for the minimum of values > 0 only, i.e. something like `data$posmin <- do.call(pmin, c(replace(data, data == 0, NA), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @markus That's right. I'm looking for values strictly greater than zero

Comment: another similar way would be `data$posmin <- do.call(pmin, '[<-'(data, data <=0, value=Inf))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  Thanks, that is a compact option

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is suitable here:

```
> data$posmin <- apply(data, 1, function(x) min(x[x>0]))
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      A     B     C posmin
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   1.1   0.2   5.2    0.2
2   3     1     1.3    1  
3   2     2.4   3.7    2  
4   4     1.1   1.7    1.1
5   0     1.3   1.3    1.3
6   1.3   0     1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution similar to `apply()`, using the `purrr` package:

```
data %>% mutate(posmin = pmap(data, min))
```